# The limit of sequence tends to $0$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

I am trying to show that if $0<x<1$,  $$ \lim_{n\to \infty}  {n^2 x^n (1-x)}=0 $$

I can't think of a clever way to show it.

Comment: Abandoning cleverness, l'Hôpital $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} (n^2/ (1/x)^n)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because of
$$\left|\frac{(n+1)^2 x^{n+1} (1-x)}{n^2 x^n (1-x)}\right| = \frac{(n+1)^2}{n^2}x\stackrel{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow} x \lt 1$$

The **series**
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {n^2 x^n (1-x)}$$
converges absolutely

Hence ${n^2 x^n (1-x)}$ has to tend to zero.

Answer (score 0):

My way of solving it would be to introduce

$$u_n = n^2 x^n (1-x)$$

The ratio $ \frac{u_{n+1}}{u_{n}} $ is given by

$$ \frac{u_{n+1}}{u_{n}} = x \, \left[ \frac{n+1}{n} \right]^{2} $$

We have $\lim\limits_{n \to + \infty} \frac{n+1}{n} = 1$.
As $|x| < 1$, for $n$ large enough we will have $\left| \frac{u_{n+1}}{u_{n}} \right| < 1$.

It means that for $n$ large enough, the terms of the sequence can be bounded by a geometric progression, with a ratio strictly inferior to $1$.

Hence, we have $\lim\limits_{n\to+\infty}u_{n}=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Write $n^2x^n=\exp(2\ln n+n\ln x)$. The argument of the exponential is equivalent to $n\ln x$ when $n\to\infty$. As $0<x<1$, $\ln x<0$ so $n\ln x\to-\infty$ and then $\exp(2\ln n+n\ln x)\to 0$.